# C# How image is stored in MemoryStream

Tags: c#, image, stream

I work on a project where i need to process a image i receive from a socket and to display it.

I'm getting the image in `jpeg` format,and  i cannot just use the `Image.FromStream());` method for retrieving the image,because it contains more data and i want to process it while i'm reading the data-for efficiency reasons.(Basically what i want is to read the image from the stream manually).
Is there any source which explaines how these image are stored in the `MemoryStream`?

The `MemoryStream` is built on a byte[] buffer,i resuse the same buffer also and i do not create a new MemoryStream everytime the method called.
A sample of code:

```
    private byte[] BlockToJpeg()
    {       
        Bitmap block=new Bitmap("...");
        MemoryStream ms=new MemoryStream();
        block.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        return ms.GetBuffer();
    }
```

**So the call would look like this**

```
  byte[] buffer=BlockToJpeg();
  sck.Send(buffer);//sending the buffer...not the full code because this is not our problem.
```

Now in the Reciver side,when i'll get that buffer:

```
Byte[] RecieveBuffer=sck.Recieve();//again,kind of pseudo code,because this is not the relevant part.
```

i have to processes it's pixels,so i'll prefer to read them from the `byte[] array` one by one manually...
Is there any structure for reading this(in our case-reading a jpeg image stored as byte array)?
For example- first 4 bytes are width,second are height...3rd are PixelFormat and the rest are the pixels values...or somthing...?

Thanks.

Comment: Images are not stored in MemoryStreams unless you put them there. You need to ask whoever is filling the MemoryStream how they chose to layout the data. The data itself is just a representation of the file, it is layed out exactly like it is layed out when you have the file on the hard drive.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain alright..i added a short example of code in the question to make is easier to understand..

Comment: In your update, BlockToJpeg does not make much sense, what are you trying to do there? Just trying to figure out the filesize if you converted a png to a jpeg? (Also you really should be disposing of all `Bitmap` or `Image` objects you create)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain updated again :)

Comment: *"i resuse the same buffer also and i do not create a new MemoryStream everytime the method called"*, that is not what your sample is doing. You are creating a new buffer every time the function is called.

Comment: Your wording is confusing. You say that you are receiving the image in "jpeg format" so that should pretty much answer your question. Hopefully you know where the "file" starts but if you don't then you can look for bytes `FFD8FF` at the start and apply some additional heuristics (see the spec). Then to find the end scan the byte stream until you read `FFD9`.

Comment: Your question is confusing. What exactly is your problem? If you already know which bytes in the first memory stream contain your image, then you will have to extract those bytes and stick them into a *second* memory stream, then you can feed that second stream into `Image.FromStream()` or `new Bitmap(Stream)`. If *you* don't know which bytes are and aren't the `jpeg` then neither do we -- this is a direct response to your only question, "Is there any source which explaines how these image are stored in the MemoryStream?"

Comment: If you want to process the data after the image at the same time you're reading the image, then you have to know beforehand where the image ends. Which means that the data you receive must have that information. Without it, what you're asking isn't possible.

Comment: @Quantic updated the question.. i guess i've asked it unclearly before but i hope now you can better understand

Comment: @JimMischel also for you :)

Comment: So you're wanting to decode a JPEG image from the raw bytes? Not impossible, but there's nothing in the .NET Framework that'll do that for you directly. The problem is that JPEG is a compressed format, so you have to uncompress before you can read the pixels.

Comment: Well, I give up, I was trying to help, but apparently my answer is unrelated to your question.  Best luck, and might I suggest you describe what it is you're asking.  If you wanted to understand how the JPEG format works, why not ask that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

jpeg is  type of compression method usually on images.
you can read more about it here:http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fcarc-image-compression